# How to use AND codition in ElasticSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, elasticsearch-5

I want to search with two fields in ElasticSearch, fields are:

1) SearchTerm (Textfield)

2) City (Textfield)

If I use mysql Query would be:

**if both has value**

```
select * from table where term = 'abc' AND city = 'mexico'
```

**if only term has value**

```
select * from table where term = 'abc'
```

**if only city has value**

```
select * from table where city = 'mexico'
```

How can I use this in ElasticSearch I'm trying with the following:

```
"bool" : {
"should": [
    { 
    "multi_match": {
        "query":   '"'+term.toLowerCase()+'"',
        "fields": 
        [ 
                "title", "desc" 
        ],
        "operator" : "and"
    }
    }, 
    { 
    "wildcard": {
        "city": {
            value: city.toLowerCase()
        }
    }
    }  
],
}
```

Please help

Thanks

Randheer

Answer (score 2):

And conditions can be modeled with a `must` clause in your [bool query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html)

Edit:
I understood your question and your city query is not right it should be:

```
{
  "bool": {
    "should": [{
        "multi_match": {
          "query": '"' + term.toLowerCase() + '"',
          "fields":
          [
            "title", "desc"
          ],
          "operator": "and"
        }
      }, {
        "wildcard": {
          "city": city.toLowerCase()
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried that, but if I use only city then it wont work, "must" work if both the value entered it dosn't work with single field !!

Comment: Please provide the mapping of your index!

Comment: `bool:{
"must": [
    {
 "multi_match": {
     "query":   '"'+keyword.toLowerCase()+'"',
     "fields": 
     [ 
             "title", "desc" 
     ],
     "operator" : "and"
 }
    }, 
    { 
  "match":{
     "city": city.toLowerCase() 
 }
    }  
],
}`

Comment: If I use must as above it won't work with only search term

Comment: That's your query. I think it could help, to see your index mapping. You could find it on your ```elasticurl/_mapping``` address.

Comment: It dosn't have mapping..we are inserting data directly

Comment: I did use "match" instead of wildcards but it didn't work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155887/discussion-between-martinschulze-and-randheer-singh-chouhan).

Comment: sure, I'm joining chat

Answer (score 1):

Bool query with must clause(Using curl):-

1.) select * from table where term = 'abc' AND city = 'mexico'

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/indexName/_search?pretty&size=50' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'      {
"query":{
  "bool":{
    "must":[
      {
       "term":{ "city":"mexico" }
      },
      {
       "term":{ "term":"abc" }
      }
     ]
   }
  }
}';
```

2.) select * from table where term = 'abc'

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/indexName/_search?pretty&size=50' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'  {
 "query":{
   "bool":{
     "must":[{
       "term":{ "term":"abc" }
     }]
   }
 }
```

}';

3.) select * from table where city = 'mexico'

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/indexName/_search?pretty&size=50' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'   {
 "query":{
   "bool":{
     "must":[{
       "term":{ "city":"mexico" }
     }]
   }
 }
}';
```

for more details find here:-  https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html